# Blank python path

Tags: python-2.7, path, bash

When I run echo $PYTHONPATH in bash, I receive a blank line then the prompt again. My .bash_profile is this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I'm running OsX 10.10.5

What does this blank line mean?

Answer (score 1):

Blank line means the variable `PYTHONPATH` is not set with any value.

Note that `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` are 2 different variables.

`PATH` has a list of directories to find executables when running in `bash` whereas `PYTHONPATH` has a list of directories for the python interpreter to search for python modules (similar to classes for `CLASSPATH` in Java).

Hence you must use:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin"
export PYTHONPATH
```